# Window.find issue using javascript

Tags: javascript

I have implemented a mark functionality using javascript where the text entered in the search box is searched across the browser and highlights it similar to find functionality. Sometimes after highlighting the text is getting wavy red underline similar to word document error mistakes. Can someone help on this issue?

Thanks

Comment: Are you perhaps doing something with `contenteditable` and have a spellchecker enabled in your browser? In what browsers are you seeing this behaviour?

Comment: No. Iam not dealing with contenteditable and I tested this only on chrome.

Comment: Sometimes - meaning some specific words or it happens randomly?